# Is it possible to support applications with beacon technology on android devices running on versions prior to 4.3 by disabling just that module?

Tags: android, android-4.3-jelly-bean, ibeacon-android

I am working on an Android application in which i have integrated beacon technology.It is supported only on devices running on version 4.3 and above.But i want my app to be available to all devices.Is it possible to disable just that module by checking the os version and make all other features of app available to users below 4.3?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible through developing a different apk for different android versions and then releasing it in google play. Refer [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are using the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/index.html) it is fully compatible with SDK 7 and higher, although beacon functionality is not available under SDK 18.

You'll need to check for compatibility before calling any beacon functions like this:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
    // Do beacon stuff here
}
```

You can read more details about how this works here:

http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/backward-compatibility.html

Comment: I'm using Estimote library